# C++ insert an element to a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I am trying to build a priority queue using a vector that stores each element. Firstly, I wanna insert the element to the vector with its priority. I am not sure if it is possible, if not, Can someone give me another solution. 
Here is my code:

```
template <typename E>
class PriorityQueue {
private:
    std::vector<E> elements;
    E value;
    int pr; 

public:
  PriorityQueue() {}

  void insert(int priority, E element) {


  }   
};
```

Comment: use std::priority_queue

Comment: No magic. Search for position based on priority where you want to insert and then insert it.

Comment: @PriyeshKumar That has linear complexity, and it can be done logarithmically (amortized).

Comment: I suggest also take a look at std::push_heap and std::pop_heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to create an element with priority for vector:

```
 struct PriElement
    {
        int data;
        int pri;
        bool operator < ( const PriElement & other ) const
        {
            return pri < other.pri;
        }
    };

    vector<PriElement> _vector;
```

However, the real problem is to keep the vector sorted per priority.

Here is a naive implementation showing the bubble up method:

```
class PriorityQueue{

public:
    void insert( int data, int pri )
    {
        _vector.push_back(PriElement(data,pri));
        int index = _vector.size() -1;
        while ( ( index > 0 )&& (_vector[index] < _vector[index-1] ) )
        {
            swap(_vector[index],_vector[index-1]);
            index--;
        }

    }
private:

    vector<PriElement> _vector;
};
```

For any real world implementation, as mentioned, use priority_queue.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I'd really appreciate that. If possible, Can I use min-heap to insert, and which means that I have to heapify it before insert. I am not sure If my idea was making sense

Comment: That is what the code above does, heapify up, but for a vector. Heapify is usually referring to the same process applied to a BST (which is what priority_queue is btw.)

Comment: `operator <` should be `const`

Answer (score 2):

The standard algorithm (see [Introduction To Algorithms](http://www.realtechsupport.org/UB/SR/algorithms/Cormen_Algorithms_3rd.pdf) chapter 6) for doing this is as follows:

1. When pushing an item, insert it to the end of the vector, then "bubble" it up to the correct place.
2. When popping the smallest item, replace the first item (at position 0) with the the item at the end, then "bubble" it down to the correct place.

It's possible to show that this can be done with (amortized) logarithmic time (the amortization is due to the vector possibly doubling itself).

However, there is no need to implement this yourself, as the standard library contains [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) which is a container adapter using `std::vector` as its default sequence container. For example, if you define

```
std::priority_queue<int> q;
```

then `q` will be a priority queue adapting a vector.

Comment: I knew priority_queue, but I am learning data structure. So I wanna use vector or list to handle that.